# Proof that if a function is computable with standard programs it is computable with Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques

Where can i find a proof related to the subject mentioned?

Comment: You will need to formally define what standard programs are. But the proof is not so interesting – it's mostly very tiring.

Comment: The proof would just be building a compiler (and proving it correct).

Answer (score 1):

To write a proof, you need to define your claim precisely. "Standard programs" is not a precise term.

However, if we define "standard program" to be, for example, any valid program in the C programming language, then you can write a proof. To prove this, you describe how to simulate any valid C-program with a Turing machine, or describe a "compiler" that takes a C-program and outputs an equivalent Turing machine. Since the C-language has many features, the proof will be long and tedious, but it is doable. I don't know if anybody has gone through the trouble to write a full formal proof.